# AndroidでVideoViewを使っての動画再生不可の場合にToast表示

Tags: android, eclipse, videoview

Androidアプリケーションをeclipseを使って作っています。
VideoViewで動画再生時に再生不可の場合に動画が再生できませんと(OK)ボタンもいっしょに出てくるものを、Toast表示のみにしたい（時間が経てば消える）と思っています。

```
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "エラーが発生しました。", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

しかし、Toast行で
「型 Toast のメソッド makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) は引数 (new Runnable(){}, String, int) に適用できません」
というエラーが発生します。このthisがnew Runnable(){}になるからだと思いますが、解決する方法がわかりません。

ご存知の方ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java (Android) ではよく使うケースですが、外側で一端、別の final 変数に保持して、それを与えてやればいいです。

```
final Context context = this;
videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    ...
    Toast.makeText(context, "エラーが発生しました。", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`(その外側クラス名).this`とする方法があります。
例えばMainActivity.javaの場合、`MainActivity.this`と書けます。